# Как работать с чатом?

Tags: поддержка, чат

Я, наверное, полный идиот, но - как работать с чатом? Я вижу, что мне есть сообщение в чате. Захожу. Все, что вижу - показано на рисунке. Что ни тычу, никак ответить не могу. Искал какой-то help - не нашел. :(

Вобщем, может, я лучше e-mail укажу, если кому надо со мной связаться? :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Откровенно говоря, чаты вообще со мной не дружат, а я с ними - в свое время сколько ни бился, тот же irc так и не смог победить :)

Comment: да, заходи, там и про плюсы есть чатик, нужно больше спецов

Comment: Ну как там, получается? Мы в чате сидим, ждём )

Comment: Как я понимаю прилетает линк не на чат, а на историю чата, а вот справа от истории можно увидить ссылку на чат, с которого прилетело и там уже можно нажать на ссылку чата или `join N users in this room now`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, зависит от того, сколько времени прошло, может и так и так

Answer (score 5):

Если не видите справа оранжевых кнопок, то вам наверное нужно [залогиниться ТУТ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com).

Если видите оранжевые кнопки, жмите верхнюю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внизу появится текстовое поле, в нём можно будет писать. Добро пожаловать!

Comment: А дальше? Ни хрена там нет... - http://i82.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1011/f4/58b74f94dcf666fb712a4dbc5a4a05f4.jpg Вобщем, хрен с ним, давайте отвечу вам тут, проще будет - словом, забирайте список, добавляйте его в тот ответ, ну, или что вам кажется наиболее разумным. Никаких претензий к тому, что вы с ним будете делать, не имею :)

Comment: @Harry там ниже еле видная ссылочка "... logged in...". Тыкайте в неё.

Comment: И регистрироваться заново, ради того, чтоб один раз ответить? Там какие-то варианты входа через FB :) или новая регистрация... Спасибо за ответы, но в любом случае, как очень ярко выраженный интроверт, чаты все равно не люблю...

Comment: @Harry там та же самая учётная запись. Просто логин отдельно на сайт, отдельно в чатики. Вводите тот же самый логин и пароль, что и тут )

Comment: @harry Да мы там в большинстве интроверты, нормально. :) Надо бы обсудить, как лучше оформить список литературы про алгоритмы.

Comment: @Harry ладно, пока вы разбираетесь — не возражаете, если я ваш вопрос и ответ про алгоритмы восстановлю и мы туда перенесём часть про алгоритмы из другого ответа?

Comment: @Harry общими я сделал вопрос и ответ потому, что так у нас заведено )

Comment: Не возражаю ни против чего :) А насчет "разбираться" - ну, если вопрос решен, то... буду разбираться в другой раз, когда совсем приспичит :)